# Why addCondition between two expression fields does not work?

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I'm building a model to list the students that have a birthday during the current month:
BUt this returns no records, although there are some that really match, is this not the right way to add a condition bases on two fields coming from addExpression?
Whats the right way?

```
class Model_Student_ThisMonthBirthday extends Model_Student {
  function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addExpression('birthdayMonth')->set("month(birthDate)");
    $this->addExpression('currentMonth')->set("month(now())");

    $this->addCondition('birthdayMonth','currentMonth');
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem using php function: date("n") insted of 'currentMonth'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument by default is a value, so if you want to use field in there, you should do this:

```
$this->addCondition('birthdayMonth', $this->getElement('currentMonth'));
```